# Spark Job failed due to OOM while reading huge files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my spark configuration

```
Nodes: 6
Cores: 66 
Memory: 72.6 GB
```

[image]

I am trying to process 3 xml files with the data 12GB+1GB+1GB

Spark properties are

```
  spark:
    default:
      parallelism: 100
      fetchSize: 3000
    executor:
      memory: 12G
      instances: 3
    driver:
      memory: 12G
      maxResultSize: 2G
```

I am also trying to cache the RDDS/rowset into memory.

```
Dataset<Row> productData = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "Feed")
    .schema(schma)
    .load(inputFile)
    .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
```

But my job is failing with out of memory issue.

Please help me to fix this

Comment: How do you get 6 workers when you set 3 executor instances? Or you mean anything else by "workers"?

Comment: @GrishaWeintraub Its spark cluster config as I shown in picture. They are 6 nodes

Comment: My guess is that XML is not splittable so it should be read as a whole, and since you have only 12GB of memory per executor, makes sense it would fail for file of 12GB. Can you try to increase the executor memory?

Comment: @GrishaWeintraub. Since each node has just 12GB, can I increase beyond that through conf

Comment: Can't you use nodes with more memory, or maybe somehow split 12GB file?